# Add function to add element on all page

Tags: functions

I would like to add a function to add for example a link in the top and in the bottom of all my pages. The best would be to create a plugin in order to activate or disable it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: To be more clear, I want to add a div at the top of each page/post/everything when the user will be logged. And I want to close the div and add other at the bottom of each page/post/everything

Comment: Did you try the `wp_head` and `wp_footer` hooks ? Please add all that extra info into the question itself.

Comment: Well, actually I don't know how to use it

Comment: I would suggest searching this site and the WordPress Codex for examples. So much stuff has been written about these hooks ;-)

Comment: I would rather use a different div class for logged in users if that's a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to create a function in your plugin. To have it display only to logged in users use:

```
   if (is_user_logged_in()) {
```

then use the wp_head and wp_footer links to add actions to display the link you want, ie:

```
 add_action('wp_head','your_function');
 add_action('wp_footer', 'your_function');
```

Comment: Works like a charme